# Drive Item Detect Sharing Changes via Delta and Notifications

Tags: graph, permissions, delta

I'm having trouble detecting sharing/permissions changes (e.g. shared link) for drive items. Couple of issues I'm running into:

**Issue 1:**

When Calling Delta:

returns very little information about a shared drive item
E.g:

```
"shared": {
                "scope": "users"
            }
```

If I require more information I may call the permissions api:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0

So I thought I will try and expand permissions via $expand when calling delta e.g.:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!2sYXPZYs-EWuKr_Zuq-PuJXgC5oupbFGksDDgkXp5Grd_x1DWcntTY1FyJEH9caq/root/delta?$expand=permissions

Unfortunately, am receiving the following error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ea0ed04a-a4f7-4fbe-a16e-61ff0770fcc0",
            "date": "2019-07-29T19:31:37"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to avoid a "permission" call for each shared item. (I see no point in calling the API for each drive item). Any suggestions?

**Issue 2:**

I'm using "Notifications/Webhooks" to receive notifications about drive item changes. Notifications work well enough for modify, create, delete, etc...
However, I noticed that when there are "sharing/permission" changes, notifications are not sent.

Ideas? Is this a limitation? (Why is it not documented?).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an update and a partial answer:

It is possible to solve these two issues, but the solution is undocumented.
This may change in the future and Microsoft at some point may document it.
(If and when it is officially documented I'll update my answer).

If anyone is running into the same issue, the best course of action is to reach out to Microsoft through partnership channels and/or support.

Comment: can you please provide your answer from microsoft though it is not yet documented?